# LPC1769 memory assignment hardfault error

Tags: c++, arm, lpc

I am working with an LPC1769 development board and working with the free version of LPCXpresso. I am writing code that is being used for data collection and I am getting a hard fault error when I try to assign the needed number of variables for this project. The code is well within the size allowable for the compiler (120 kb of the 256 kb allowable), but if I try to initialize the number of variables I need, I get the hard fault error, which I already know is an error related to trying to assign memory to an address that is not addressable.

A lot of my code is not relevant to this error, so the text below is the relevant code.
**Initialization:**

```
#include "glob.h"
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Ticker.h"
#include "rtc_time.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
static void flip(void);
extern void po(CANMessage);             // handle 0x79X and 0x79X
extern void dime(CANMessage);           // handle 0x1FXXXXXX messages
extern void stage(CANMessage);          // handle 0x1DXXXXXX messages
extern void authen(CANMessage);         // handle 0x1BXXXXXX messages
extern void ParseInhibit(CANMessage);   // handle 0x0C14XXXX messages
extern void ParseLED(CANMessage);       // handle sounder 0x0C14XXXX messages
extern int last_data[3];                // used in gotoAsleep and gotoAwake
extern void service_switch(void);
extern void init(void);
extern void abtimeoutfunc(void);
static InterruptIn sdip(P0_4);
DigitalIn buzz(P1_15);                  // hardware pin for buzzer
extern void downloadmem(void);          // loads POs
extern void LEDset(int);                // sets the LEDs
extern int kickcan(long, char, char, char, char, char, char, char, char, int);

//CanMessage Variables
int joystickx, joysticky;
int axishandler, axistemp, axis;

//Battery Monitor variables
int datesetter;
int second, minute, hour, month, year, dayofweek, day, datehandler, hour2, day2, minute2, second2;
double ADCvoltage; //Converts the float percentage back into the value being read into the ADC pin
double batteryvoltage, chargelow;

//Cycle log variables
int chargeid;
int cyclesecond[5], cyclemonth[5], cycleminute[5], cyclehour[5], cycleday[5], cycledayofweek[5], cycleyear[5], cycle;

//Max and Min variables
double voltmaxlife, voltmaxminute, batterynibble; //Max voltage variable
double voltminlife = 30, voltminmonth = 30, voltminday = 30, voltminminute = 30; //Min voltage variable
int timedmaxsecond, timedmaxminute, timedmaxhour, timedmaxmonth, timedmaxday, timedmaxdayofweek, timedmaxyear, first = 1;
int timedminsecond, timedminminute, timedminhour, timedminmonth, timedminday, timedmindayofweek, timedminyear;
int lifemaxsecond, lifemaxminute, lifemaxhour, lifemaxmonth, lifemaxyear, lifemaxdayofweek, lifemaxday; //Time variables used to store the time of the most recent max charge across the chair's lifetime
int lifeminsecond, lifeminminute, lifeminhour, lifeminmonth, lifeminyear, lifemindayofweek, lifeminday; //Time variables used to store the time of the most recent min charge
int dailymaxsecond, dailymaxminute, dailymaxhour, dailymaxmonth, dailymaxday, dailymaxdayofweek, dailymaxyear;
int dailyminsecond, dailyminminute, dailyminhour, dailyminmonth, dailyminday, dailymindayofweek, dailyminyear;
double voltagereadweek1[12], voltagereadweek2[12], voltagereadweek3[12], voltagereadweek4[12], voltagereadweek5[12], voltagereadweek6[12], voltagereadweek7[12], voltagereadweek8[12], voltagereadweek9[12], voltagereadweek10[12], voltagereadweek11[12], voltagereadweek12[12], voltagereadweek13[12], voltagereadweek14[12];
double voltagereadday[5], voltagereadmonth[5];
double dailymaxvolt, monthlymaxvolt, dailyminvolt = 30, monthlyminvolt = 30;
int monthlymaxsecond, monthlymaxminute, monthlymaxhour, monthlymaxmonth, monthlymaxday, monthlymaxdayofweek, monthlymaxyear;
int monthlyminsecond, monthlyminminute, monthlyminhour, monthlyminmonth, monthlyminday, monthlymindayofweek, monthlyminyear;
bool hourset = true;

//Inhibit variables
int inhibit4second, inhibit4minute, inhibit4hour, inhibit4month, inhibit4day, inhibit4dayofweek, inhibit4year, inhibit4band;
int inhibit5second, inhibit5minute, inhibit5hour, inhibit5month, inhibit5day, inhibit5dayofweek, inhibit5year, inhibit5band;
int inhibit2second, inhibit2minute, inhibit2hour, inhibit2month, inhibit2day, inhibit2dayofweek, inhibit2year, inhibit2band;
int inhibit3second, inhibit3minute, inhibit3hour, inhibit3month, inhibit3day, inhibit3dayofweek, inhibit3year, inhibit3band;
int inhibitdata, inhibitcan;
extern int inhibits[4];
extern int tempinhibit, tempband;

//Error variables
int errordata1[50], errordata2[50], batteryhandler;
int batteryerror1, batteryerror2, batteryerrorsecond, batteryerrorminute, batteryerrorhour, batteryerrorday, batteryerrordayofweek, batteryerrormonth, batteryerroryear;
double batteryerrorvoltage;
int errorsecond[5], errorminute[5], errorhour[5], errorday[5], errordayofweek[5], errormonth[5], erroryear[5];

//Event variables
int programchangecount, programsecond[5], programminute[5], programhour[5], programday[5], programdayofweek[5], programmonth[5], programyear[5];
int eventkind, eventlog[5], eventsecond[5], eventminute[5], eventhour[5], eventday[5], eventdayofweek[5], eventmonth[5], eventyear[5];
int profile, prosecond[5], prominute[5], prohour[5], promonth[5], proday[5], proyear[5], prodayofweek[5];
int OBP, cd, mode, previousmode, inhibitreset, previousevent, eventhappen, charging;

//Memory Variables
I2C i2c(P0_10, P0_11); //Establish the I2C protocol
int typevalue, readlength, ackholder, readwrite, secondreturn, minutereturn,     hourreturn, monthreturn, dayreturn, dayofweekreturn, yearreturn, cyclereturn;
double batteryreturn;
double doubleconvert;
char readdata;
int addressholder1, addressholder2, addresshandle;
char temp1, temp2;
char yraddress1[124], yraddress2[124], secaddress1[618], secaddress2[618], minaddress1[618], minaddress2[618], hraddress1[618], hraddress2[618], monaddress1[618], monaddress2[618], daddress1[618], daddress2[618];
char dowaddress1[309], dowaddress2[309];
/*char * writeaddress = (char *) malloc(1);
char * readaddress = (char *) malloc(1);
char * readout = (char *) malloc(1);
char * newholder = (char *) malloc(1);
char * writedata = (char *) malloc(1);
char * convertholder = (char *) malloc(5);
char * doubleconvertbuffer = (char *) malloc(5);*/


char wait_msg[8] = {0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0};// Used for Queued messages
char DimeID[8] =  {1,2, 3,4, 5,6, 7,8}; // Appendex A B.1 Protocol Spec.
char auth[8]   =  {0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0};
int AvailProfiles, AvailModes, CurrentPro, CurrentMo, ProMask[8];
int MyNode, repo, CxSM;                 // everybody uses these
int modulenumber = 1;
int flag;                               // assigned by LAST can.write
extern int realspeed;                   // used by set speed
enum BusState {Asleep, Awake};          // state of the bus
BusState MyState=Asleep;
Timeout timeout;                        // use to goto Sleep -- used for SCID
extern Timeout abTimer;                 // when calling gotoAsleep, detach latched actuators
extern int color5[10];  // init
extern Ticker LEDticker;
```

**Variable Assignment**

```
void addressing(){
int add = 1;
secaddress1[0] = ' ';
secaddress2[0] = ' ';
minaddress1[0] = '&';
minaddress2[0] = 'P';
hraddress1[0] = '-';
hraddress2[0] = '!';
monaddress1[0] = '3';
monaddress2[0] = 'Q';
daddress1[0] = ':';
daddress2[0] = '"';
dowaddress1[0] = '@';
dowaddress2[0] = 'R';
yraddress1[0] = 'C';
yraddress2[0] = 'j';
while(add < sizeof(secaddress1))
{
    temp1 = secaddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = secaddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(secaddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        secaddress1[add] = secaddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        secaddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(secaddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        secaddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        secaddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
add = 1;
while(add < sizeof(minaddress1))
{
    temp1 = minaddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = minaddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(minaddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        minaddress1[add] = minaddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        minaddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(minaddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        minaddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        minaddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
add = 1;
while(add < sizeof(hraddress1))
{
    temp1 = hraddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = hraddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(hraddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        hraddress1[add] = hraddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        hraddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(hraddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        hraddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        hraddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
add = 1;
while(add < sizeof(monaddress1))
{
    temp1 = monaddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = monaddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(monaddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        monaddress1[add] = monaddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        monaddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(monaddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        monaddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        monaddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
add = 1;
while(add < sizeof(daddress1))
{
    temp1 = daddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = daddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(daddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        daddress1[add] = daddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        daddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(daddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        daddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        daddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
add = 1;
while(add < sizeof(dowaddress1))
{
    temp1 = dowaddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = dowaddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(dowaddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        dowaddress1[add] = dowaddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        dowaddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(dowaddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        dowaddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        dowaddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
add = 1;
while(add < sizeof(yraddress1))
{
    temp1 = yraddress1[add-1];
    temp2 = yraddress2[add-1];
    addressholder1 = temp1;
    addressholder2 = temp2;
    if(yraddress2[add-1] != '~'){
        yraddress1[add] = yraddress1[add-1];
        addresshandle = addressholder2 + 1;
        yraddress2[add] = addresshandle;

    }
    if(yraddress2[add-1] == '~'){
        addresshandle = addressholder1 + 1;
        yraddress1[add] = addresshandle;
        yraddress2[add] = ' ';
    }
    add++;
}
addressholder1 = addressholder2;
}
```

When I remove the section for year address at the end, the code works fine and the hard fault does not show up. If I reduce the amount of year addresses to between 1-50, it works, but when it goes above 100 year address, I get the hard fault shown below.

**Hard Fault error message from debug:**

```
HardFault_Handler() at 0xf8 
() at 0xfffffff9    
_free_r() at 0xcfb2 
__sflush_r() at 0xcb56  
setvbuf() at 0xe6b6 
mbed::Stream::Stream() at 0x9be2    
mbed::Serial::Serial() at 0x968a    
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0() at glob.h:24 0x7ee8 
_GLOBAL__sub_I_map() at stage.cpp:568 0x7fd6    
__libc_init_array() at 0xd81a   
ResetISR() at 0x16c
```

If there is anything else I need to post, just ask. Thank you!

Comment: You probably should step through with the debugger, to catch where the error actually occurs.

Comment: I would, but with the address I mentioned included, the hard fault handler throws an error before I can use the step function. I start the debugger and the error is thrown before I get control back.

Comment: One of your global variables is going boom. From the looks of things it's a serial port. 2 questions: Can you put a breakpoint in the constructor and Does it have to be a global variable?

Comment: How are you compiling? check the linker file and your compiled object, maybe your RAM section is bigger than the available memory on the LPC. 256K are of flash memory (RO), the available RAM is smaller.